# Select records where all rows have same value in two columns in a single row

Tags: mysql

Here is my sample table

```
Col1 Col2
A      A
B      B
A      C
B      D
C      C
```

I want to be able to select distinct records where all rows have the same value in Col1 and Col2. So my answer should be

```
Col1 Col2
A       A
B       B
C       C
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
select distinct * from t where col1 = col2;
```

if both cols have `null` and you want to get that row too:

```
select distinct * from t where coalesce(col1, col2) is null or col1 = col2;
```

Comment: distinct * is oxymoronic

Answer (score 0):

The query is already written in your request:

> **select distinct records** where all rows have **the same value in Col1 and Col2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Col1 = Col2
```